# How to check if $data variable is set with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I set a data like `$data['say_something'] = 'Hello';` and send it to the view with `$this->load->view('my_page', $data);`, how can I check in the view if the variable $say_something is set? Is there a Codeigniter function to this or something?

Comment: you do not need any codeigniter function to do that, `isset` is enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to do with codeigniter here. It's basic `PHP`.

```
if(isset($say_something)){
   echo $say_something;
}
else{
   echo "variable is not there";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just thought there could be an alternative Codeigniter function for isset().

Comment: Just a note that - isset() will trow an error with $this->input->post('variable_name') variables.
See my answer below

Answer (score 7):

`isset` will not work with $this->input->post('variable_name') variables:

CodeIgniter comes with helper methods that let you fetch `POST, GET, COOKIE` or `SERVER` items.

The main advantage of using the provided methods rather than fetching an item directly `($_POST['something'])` - is that the methods will check to see if the item is set and return NULL if not.

This lets you conveniently use data without having to test whether an item exists first. In other words, normally you might do something like this:

```
$something = isset($_POST['something']) ? $_POST['something'] : NULL;
```

With CodeIgniter’s built in methods you can simply do this:

```
$something = $this->input->post('something');
```

Reference: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Answer (score 1):

In case it was set, but to null or wrong type of data, you may also want to check for empty($foo), in this fashion:

if(isset($say_something) && !empty($say_something)) {...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all the variables sent to the view, try using this:

```
var_dump($this->_ci_cached_vars);
```

Answer (score 0):

use **[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)** function

> isset() function checks whether a variable is set or not, if it is set it will return **true** and **false** otherwise.

You can use it with conditional statements

> ```
>  if(isset($foo))
>    {//foo is set}
>    else
>    {//foo is not set}
> ```

**Source** :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use var_dump($data)